# What would be the decomposition of $E[p^n]$?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a PID $R$. Then there are idelas $I_1=(a_1),~I_2=(a_2)~ \cdots, I_n=(a_n)$ of $R$ such that $I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq I_n$ such that $$M \cong R/I_1 \oplus R/I_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus R/I_n, ~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
that is, $M$ can be written as a direct sum of cyclic $R$-modules.

---

Now, let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the ring of $p$-adic integers. Let $E[p^n]$ be the set of $p^n$-torsion points. Then $E[p^n]$ is finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module.

> What would be the decomposition of $E[p^n]$ similar to that of $(1)$ ?

We note that $E[p] \subseteq E[p^2] \subseteq \cdots E[p^n]$. For any $p^n$-torsion point $P$, there is a $p^{n-1}$-torsion point $Q$ such that $pQ=P$.  So I think in this case we have $$I_1=(p) \supseteq I_2=(p^2) \supseteq \cdots I_n=(p^n)$$ so that we have $$E[p^n] \cong \mathbb{Z}_p/p \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p/p^2 \mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p/p^n \mathbb{Z}_p.$$

Is it correct ?

Comment: Nope. You can see just by counting cardinalities that that's wrong. $E[p^n]$ is just $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^2$. So $I_1 = I_2 = (p^n)$. It's pretty boring considered just as a $\mathbb Z_p$-module. All the interesting structure comes from the Galois action.

Comment: Also the fact that $E[p^n]$ is a $\mathbb Z_p$ module has nothing to do with the fact that $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, Thanks a lot for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an elliptic curve (with its algebraic group law ) $$E:\{ (x,y) \in \overline{k}, y^2=x^3+ax+b\}\cup O$$ where $a,b\in k$ is a field of characteristic $0$ then $$E[m] \cong \Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$$ Whence
$$E[p^n] \cong \Bbb{Z}_p/p^n\Bbb{Z}_p\times \Bbb{Z}_p/p^n\Bbb{Z}_p$$

- $G[m] \cong \Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/m\Bbb{Z}$ is obvious for a complex torus $G=\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$
- The Weierstrass functions give some isomorphisms between complex tori and complex elliptic curves
- All the torsion points of $E$ will have their coordinates in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}(a,b)}$, that we can identify with a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$ so it suffices to prove the claim for complex elliptic curves.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Though the question is silly because I already knew $E[p^n]$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$-module of rank $2$.